# Creating an a.out executable from scratch

Tags: c, unix, compiler-construction, executable, machine-code

I have created a programming language, from scratch with C. I have built a compiler which processes the code in the input file and converts it to tokens and checks that the tokens are in the correct order. I am on the final step of the compiler: Output/Executable. I want to create an output that can run in terminal. I want to create an a.out output but the only resource I could find was [this from nasm](http://opensource.apple.com/source/nasm/nasm-13/nasm/output/outaout.c) which doesn't really help me.

So my question is, how do I create an a.out file (unix executable) that I can run in terminal?

Comment: The "easiest" way is to generate assembly code, and then use an existing assembler + linker to generate the final executable.

Comment: I think you should read some ELF documentation.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I want to do all of the processing an compilation inside of my application

Comment: Then you *do* need to check out the nasm source you mentioned. The function `aout_write` creates a new executable from scratch, and as you can see it's not as simple as "just output the raw code".

Comment: .. although I suppose you could try another route. Write a bytecode parser for your own language, and append your bytecode to that.

Comment: pick a format, a.out, elf, intel hex, etc, find the details about that format, and just create that file.  It is that simple, in the time it took me to write this I googled the a.out format and found details.

Comment: @dwelch Could you share those details, because I haven't found any.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=a.out+file+format

Comment: If you don't mind C++, there are many great resources on using LLVM to compile things for you.

Comment: This question is essentially about how to write a linker for an unspecifed output format. It is not only far too broad for SO but unanswerable in its present form. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you wrote you are on the final step of the compiler ...

- are you sure ?
- what type of language is it ?
- for example non asm languages like Pascal/C/C++ require engine

as have been mentioned before in comments you can:

1. use existing assembler compiler/linker from your app

   - this is the simplest way
   - you need to create language runtime engine code in asm
   - then compile your source to asm
   - put these 2 sources together
   - and call compiler/linker
   - but you can forget about breakpoints and trace ...
   - also there are C/C++ compilers/linkers out there if you dislike asm
2. create own compiler linker

   - first you need to study executable fileformat
   - create an template for it
   - second you need to write your own asm compiler
   - do not need to be for complete instruction set
   - just to have all necessary things to translate your language to the machine code
   - then just compile your language to machine code
   - and fill the template with code and all necessary data
   - save it as a.out ...

The language runtime engine:

- it is something like OS for your program
- set of subroutines your language supports
- like interface between terminal/real OS and your program
- memory/resources management
- handles local/global/static variables
- heap/stack ...
- threads
- debugging
- and much more ...